# Python AWS Boto URL Connection Error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, boto, boto3

I'm trying to create an AWS machine learning model in Python BOTO:

```
import boto3
from boto3.session import Session
import uuid

session = Session(aws_access_key_id='...', aws_secret_access_key='...', region_name='us-west-1')
client = session.client('machinelearning')

response = client.create_ml_model(
    MLModelId=str(uuid.uuid4()),
    MLModelName='banking',
    MLModelType='BINARY',
    TrainingDataSourceId='...',
)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://machinelearning.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/"

I don't believe the region_name is the problem. Could this be a permission problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the region is the issue. Amazon Machine Learning is only available currently in the Virginia and Ireland regions as [per documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#machinelearning_region)

[image]

Comment: To add on to this, you can get a list of the regions known to be supported by a service at the time of your version of botocore's release. [Docs.](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.get_available_regions) Be aware that you will need to update your client to get updates to this list even though you will be able to use new regions without updating.

Comment: Wow thanks, I never would have realized. Seems like the error message should mention that.